# Select an element with jQuery selector regardless of ID

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I have the following code:

```
<div>
 <div id="someID"><h1>Blah</h1></div>
 <div id="someID2"><h1>Blah</h1></div>
</div>
```

and I am trying to select  in jQuery (for the accordion in jQuery UI). However, the following does not work unless I remove the ID from the div.

```
$('> div > h1')
```

Is there some way to tell the selector to ignore the ID, or am I going about this the wrong way?

Edit: The actual use I'm going for is in the sortable accordion in jQuery UI, with IDs on the div elements. An example of what I'm doing, with source, can be found here:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#sortable

---

**Edit: As I have a feeling this may be related to jQueryUI, rather than the selectors themselves, below is the code I'm actually trying to run.**

http://jsfiddle.net/Zgkj4/1/

Working example without ID in div:

http://jsfiddle.net/Zgkj4/2/

Comment: First of all, replace `</blah>` with `</h1>`

Comment: yeah, that `</blah>` is hopefully not what he's actually using

Comment: Yup, my bad - in trying to simplify the example I slipped up typing it here.

Answer (score 2):

You could try selecting the `<h1>` with a parent `<div>` that has an `id` attribute

```
$("div > div[id] > h1")
```

---

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/YjSvU/

---

ignores `div` w/o `id`: http://jsfiddle.net/YjSvU/1/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your selector should be a string, like this:

```
$('div > h1')
```

Comment: Oops, that was a typo in the post - in my code it is a string.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector needs to be a string, so wrap it in single (`'`) or double quotes (`"`).

Also `> div` does not make sense, as `>` is direct descendant / [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/), and you have no parent on the left hand side (or otherwise context). Remove the leading `>`.

[See it *not* working on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/LF7hx/).

Answer (score 1):

http://codylindley.com/jqueryselectors/. A list of all jquery selectors. it should help you allot.

Answer (score 0):

Use quotes, and im not sure about the first >

This should work:

$("div > h1")

Comment: As above, forgot the quotes in the post. However, I've tried without the first gt, with no luck. I'll update the original post with a bit more information.